# How to use 'javascript variable as a text'?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, fullcalendar

Sorry for posting this again, but I can't find anything useful on the internet.
I'm trying to create a calendar. I'm using symfony 3 and [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to create it.
So in my `twig` class I've created a variable:

```
{% set fff = "" %}
```

Into `fff` variable I add some text like `{start: "2017-05-17", title: "Take my mom from airport"},`
Then I pass the `fff` variable to JS:

```
<script>
    var allTasks = {{ fff|json_encode()|raw }};
</script>
```

Then if I want to add this task `{start: "2017-05-17", title: "Take my mom from airport"},`, *allTasks variable*, to the calendar. So I've created a function:

```
$(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         events: [
             //there I should add tasks
             //f.e. {start: "2017-05-17", title: "Take my mom from airport"},
             //this code adds a task into my calendar 
         ],
     });
 });
```

When I put code like in the example it works fine, but when I try to do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
            allTasks, //this variable is equal to "{start: "2017-05-17", title: "Take my mom from airport"},"
        ],
     });
 });
```

This gives me nothing. Even calendar disappear from my web.
So the question is what I'm doing wrong? allTasks var prints out `{start: "2017-05-17", title: "Take my mom from airport"},`. I've tested it, but when I try to use it inside my function it doesn't work.

Error log:
`[2017-05-15 11:40:36] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /[%7Bstart:'2017-05-17',title:'Take%20my%20mom%20from%20airport'%7D]" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home")" at /home/david/task_manager/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 3497 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /[%7Bstart:'2017-05-17',title:'Take%20my%20mom%20from%20airport'%7D]\" (from \"http://127.0.0.1:8000/home\") at /home/david/task_manager/var/cache/dev/classes.php:3497, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/david/task_manager/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:162)"} []`
[image: example]
[image: example]

Comment: does there any errors in your console log ?

Comment: JavaScript probably doesn't like that you have a comma after last element in the events array - this is a difference between PHP and JavaScript (PHP forgives you trailing commas)

Comment: Another thing - scopes. Is `allTasks` defined on a global scope? Or maybe the `<script>` tag around it's definition - does your browser accept it without any type/language attribute? E.g. does `console.log(allTasks)` actually print anything out?

Comment: @mkilmanas I've tried to print `allTasks` variable into my web and it prints out the text I need.

Comment: @mkilmanas No, you are right. The comma is causing a syntax error, thus preventing the rest of the JS to execute. That's why OP is not seeing the calendar at all

Comment: @hassan added error log :)

Comment: this is the wrong approach really, inserting static events into the calendar isn't much good unless you have got a tiny number and the user isn't likely to keep changing the view to different dates. If you've got more than a couple of hundred events in your database (or predict that you will have after the app has been running for some time), then loading all of them at once at startup will be too slow and expensive. Instead, define an ajax endpoint where fullCalendar can fetch the events it needs each time the view changes. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<script>
    var allTasks = '{{ fff|json_encode()|raw }}'; // make sure that fff return {'start': '2017-05-17', 'title': 'Take my mom from airport'}
</script>

$(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
            JSON.parse(allTasks)
        ],
     });
 });
```